# How to use Link Manager

Tags: plugins, links

I'm working on a plugin and want to use WordPress's 'link manager' (see following image).

[image: Link Manager]

How can I use it?

I used Google to find an answer but I couldn't.

I also figured out that this option was disabled with Wordpress 3.5?!
And [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/link-manager/) should help me out. I installed it but I can't figure out how it works or what I have to do with it.

Comment: But, did the `Links` menu item appear in your dashboard?

Comment: Yes, the Links menu item is in my dashboard! :)

Comment: [This](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/69639/12615) is a simple solution. The snapshot you're showing is way too difficult, IMO.